# CRS definitions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, srid

I have a drone software package that wants to output my data in CRS 32612.  QGIS seems to load and view it fine but when I extract contours from a DEM at this projection it tries to write the temporary layer to CRS 4326 which in theory would be fine but the contours are in outer space!  When I try to change the contour layer to CRS 26912 or 32612 they come back in view but are not overlaying the DEM.  (Miss by about 350m to the west.)  I assume this is because of the magnitude of the math projecting a UTM coord it thinks is UTM back to an actual UTM.

My question is does QGIS properly handle the 326## CRS projections or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: QGIS is using Proj https://proj.org/ for coordinate operations. I believe that it can handle 326## projections well but you can make a test with some reference points and command line utilities https://proj.org/apps/index.html#apps.

Comment: Can you list the exact steps you take, any dialogs you click, maybe with screenshots?

Comment: All I am doing is extracting Contours from the Raster >> Extraction menu on a raster DEM file that was originally created in CRS 32612.  Not a lot to describe really.

Comment: How did you load your data? Did you do anything to the CRS of the data or project? Are you the data is in 32612? What is an example coordinate?

Comment: Just the usual drag and drop or the usual add a layer dialogue.  The problem appears to be the Contour generator from the Extraction menu in the Raster tools.  The GRASS contours generate just fine.